# Getting a specific value from a CSV file with Python raw_input?

Tags: python, csv

Currently, I have a CSV file set out like this:

```
Element,Weight
"Hydrogen","1"
"Oxygen","16"
```

Eventually it'll have all of the elements and their atomic weights next to them, but putting all of that in is rather pointless unless I get this issue solved first.

The main Python program is as follows:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("chem.csv", "rb"))

first = raw_input("Enter first element: ")
second = raw_input("Enter second element: ")

if first == "Hydrogen" or "hydrogen":
     for Weight in reader:
        print Weight

else:
     print "No."
```

Now, as you might be able to tell from that, my aim here is to have the program display the weight of hydrogen as taken from the CSV file, for now. However, currently it just ends up displaying the following:

```
Enter first element: hydrogen
Enter second element: oxygen
['Element', 'Weight']
['Hydrogen', '1']
['Oxygen', '16']
```

So, basically, how can I make it so that it goes to the Hydrogen row and then takes the weight value from the second column? I should be able to go from there to nail the rest of the program, but this part has got me stuck.

As a secondary thing, is it at all possible to have it so that I won't have to have what is essentially a list of elements in the main Python program as well as in the CSV file? It'd cut down a lot on the clutter, but I just can't get it figured out.

Comment: I think you mean `first == "Hydrogen" or first == "hydrogen"` by `first == "Hydrogen" or "hydrogen"`? Could also be `first in ("Hydrogen", "hydrogen")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of iterating over the data it is probably nicer to store it in an easy accessible way, e.g. a dictionary mapping name to weight. Then you can just do a look-up for the entered string and display the result (or not if there is none).

```
import csv

#Read in data anbd store it in dictionary.
#The element name will be stored in lowercase.
elemen_data = { element.lower():int(weight) for element,weight in csv.reader(open("in", "rb"))}

first = raw_input("Enter first element: ")
second = raw_input("Enter second element: ")

#Look for the weight of the entered element (after converting it to all lowercase)
weight_first = elemen_data.get(first.lower())
weight_second = elemen_data.get(second.lower())

if weight_first is not None:
    print 'First Element:', first, 'Weight:', weight_first
else:
    print 'First Element', first, 'not found'

if weight_second is not None:
    print 'Second Element:', second, 'Weight:', weight_first
else:
    print 'Second Element', second, 'not found'
```

Storing your data apart from you program logic can make sense if you want to be able to easily make changes to the data without touching the program. So having a csv-file that is read in is absolutely okay. (As long as the data has a reasonable size)

Comment: I've seen dictionaries being mentioned as a solution to this kind of thing before... But I could never figure out how to get one up and running properly. Thanks for this. I don't suppose that you'd be able to give some pointers as to how to add looking up oxygen, would you? I'd presume it uses elif, but passed that I've realized I'm completely stuck once more.

Comment: You can read about how dictionaries work in detail in the python docs (http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html), but the look-up is done in `elemen_data.get(first)`. Here it looks for whatever was entered as first and retrieves the associated data.

Comment: Ah you meant because of the capitalization. I'll add that in a minute. But basically you can just transform all strings to lowercase to avoid that problem.

Comment: Nope, not a problem with the capitalization at all before here, but I'm going to through that in anyway. Just wanted to know how I'd go about pulling the second element in that's required.

Comment: You can do the second one just like the first one, using `elemen_data.get(second.lower())`

Comment: Thinking about it, the weight should be an int... Woops. xD Yeah, second one is done now.

Comment: If it should be an int best cast it while reading in your data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you iterate over csv.reader object you receive csv file rows as lists of your row cells values. So you can try next for your case:

```
if first in ("Hydrogen", "hydrogen"):
     for Weight in reader:
        if Weight[0] == first:
            print Weight[1]
```

That's not the best code, but that returns the value you wanted.

Comment: That it does, cheers. I think I'll follow the dictionary route up above, though... When I can figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

First problem:

```
if first == "Hydrogen" or "hydrogen":
```

That won't return what you want.  You either want:

```
if first == 'Hydrogen' or first == 'hydrogen':
```

or

```
if first in ['Hydrogen', 'hydrogen']:
```

Or better yet:

```
if first.lower() == 'hydrogen'
```

Which would work for all capitalizations, like HYDrogen.

Then, in that you can do what you want:

```
for row in reader:
    if row[0].lower() == first.lower():
        print row[1]
```

Of course, this could be cleaned up a bit by using a dictionary of values; you probably don't want an `if` statement for every element, but there you go.

Comment: Yeah, the large quantities of if statements are largely because I'm really just starting out, so things like dictionaries and how to create them was... a bit complicated for me. But hey, it's a learning process; I reckon I should be able to at least make a dictionary out of CSV file from now on, which is some kind of progress.